# Listception... Extracting data from a list within a list within a list

Tags: r, json, indexing, lapply

Hey stack overflow legends,

I'm trying to extract a dataframe from a nested list within a nested list, and it feels like I'm stuck in some kind of Inception-like dream within a dream. These lists are just nesting inside each other indefinitely, it's like a never-ending Russian doll situation.

I'm using the following Trademe API call (https://api.trademe.co.nz/v1/Categories/0153-.xml) and the data is structured somewhat like this:

```
{
  "Category": {
    "Name": "Fashion",
    "Subcategories": [
      {
        "Name": "Women's Clothing",
        "Number": "0153-0154-",
        "Path": "Fashion/Women's Clothing",
        "Subcategories": [
          {
            "Name": "Dresses",
            "Number": "0153-0154-0155-",
            "Path": "Fashion/Women's Clothing/Dresses",
            "Subcategories": []
          },
          {
            "Name": "Tops",
            "Number": "0153-0154-0156-",
            "Path": "Fashion/Women's Clothing/Tops",
            "Subcategories": []
          },
          ...
        ]
      },
      {
        "Name": "Men's Clothing",
        "Number": "0153-0157-",
        "Path": "Fashion/Men's Clothing",
        "Subcategories": [
          {
            "Name": "Shirts",
            "Number": "0153-0157-0158-",
            "Path": "Fashion/Men's Clothing/Shirts",
            "Subcategories": []
          },
          {
            "Name": "Pants",
            "Number": "0153-0157-0159-",
            "Path": "Fashion/Men's Clothing/Pants",
            "Subcategories": []
          },
          ...
        ]
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to extract a dataframe with three columns: "Name", "Number", and "Path". The "Name" column should contain the names of all the subcategories, the "Number" column should contain their corresponding numbers, and the "Path" column should contain their full paths. I really only need the data from the lowest level.

I've tried using lapply() and sapply(), but I just keep getting lost in the nested lists. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
[Your Name]

Comment: Do you want recursive extraction (also subcategories of subcategories), or a given level only?

Comment: Good point, only really need the bottom level. Updated my question now :)

Answer (score 2):

In the provided example we could do:

```r
library(jsonlite)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

jsontext |>
  fromJSON() |>
  pluck("Category", "Subcategories", "Subcategories") |>
  bind_rows() |>
  select(-Subcategories)
```

Output:

```
     Name          Number                            Path
1 Dresses 0153-0154-0155- Fashion/Womens Clothing/Dresses
2    Tops 0153-0154-0156-    Fashion/Womens Clothing/Tops
3  Shirts 0153-0157-0158-    Fashion/Mens Clothing/Shirts
4   Pants 0153-0157-0159-     Fashion/Mens Clothing/Pants
```

---

**Update**: If the subcategories is nested indefinitely (theoretically) I guess that the easiest would be to unlist it and make use of the name structure instead of doing recursions.

E.g.

```
jsonunlisted <- 
  jsontext |>
  fromJSON() |>
  pluck("Category", "Subcategories") |>
  unlist() 

cbind(Name = jsonunlisted[grep("Name", names(jsonunlisted))],
      Number = jsonunlisted[grep("Number", names(jsonunlisted))],
      Path = jsonunlisted[grep("Path", names(jsonunlisted))])
```

Output:

```r
                                  Name              Number                 Path                               
Name1                             "Womens Clothing" "0153-0154-"           "Fashion/Womens Clothing"          
Name2                             "Mens Clothing"   "0153-0157-"           "Fashion/Mens Clothing"            
Subcategories.Name1               "Dresses"         "0153-0154-0155-"      "Fashion/Womens Clothing/Dresses"  
Subcategories.Name2               "Tops"            "0153-0154-0156-"      "Fashion/Womens Clothing/Tops"     
Subcategories.Name1               "Shirts"          "0153-0157-0158-"      "Fashion/Mens Clothing/Shirts"     
Subcategories.Name2               "Pants"           "0153-0157-0159-"      "Fashion/Mens Clothing/Pants"      
Subcategories.Subcategories.Name1 "More Shirts"     "More 0153-0157-0158-" "More Fashion/Mens Clothing/Shirts"
Subcategories.Subcategories.Name2 "More Pants"      "More 0153-0157-0159-" "More Fashion/Mens Clothing/Pants"
```

---

Data:

```r
jsontext <- '{
  "Category": {
    "Name": "Fashion",
    "Subcategories": [
      {
        "Name": "Womens Clothing",
        "Number": "0153-0154-",
        "Path": "Fashion/Womens Clothing",
        "Subcategories": [
          {
            "Name": "Dresses",
            "Number": "0153-0154-0155-",
            "Path": "Fashion/Womens Clothing/Dresses",
            "Subcategories": []
          },
          {
            "Name": "Tops",
            "Number": "0153-0154-0156-",
            "Path": "Fashion/Womens Clothing/Tops",
            "Subcategories": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "Name": "Mens Clothing",
        "Number": "0153-0157-",
        "Path": "Fashion/Mens Clothing",
        "Subcategories": [
          {
            "Name": "Shirts",
            "Number": "0153-0157-0158-",
            "Path": "Fashion/Mens Clothing/Shirts",
            "Subcategories": []
          },
          {
            "Name": "Pants",
            "Number": "0153-0157-0159-",
            "Path": "Fashion/Mens Clothing/Pants",
            "Subcategories": [          {
            "Name": "More Shirts",
            "Number": "More 0153-0157-0158-",
            "Path": "More Fashion/Mens Clothing/Shirts",
            "Subcategories": []
          },
          {
            "Name": "More Pants",
            "Number": "More 0153-0157-0159-",
            "Path": "More Fashion/Mens Clothing/Pants",
            "Subcategories": []
          }]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `rrapply()` in package `rrapply`. We prune the `Name`, `Number` and `Path` elements of all nodes containing a `Path` variable (nb: the root node does not have a `Path` variable). This avoids the need for regular expressions applied to the unlisted/collapsed list names.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(rrapply)

jsontext |>
  fromJSON(simplifyVector = FALSE) |>
  rrapply(condition = \(x, .xname) .xname == "Path", f = \(x, .xsiblings) .xsiblings[c("Name", "Number", "Path")], how = "flatten") |>
  rrapply(how = "bind")

#>              Name               Number                              Path
#> 1 Womens Clothing           0153-0154-           Fashion/Womens Clothing
#> 2         Dresses      0153-0154-0155-   Fashion/Womens Clothing/Dresses
#> 3            Tops      0153-0154-0156-      Fashion/Womens Clothing/Tops
#> 4   Mens Clothing           0153-0157-             Fashion/Mens Clothing
#> 5          Shirts      0153-0157-0158-      Fashion/Mens Clothing/Shirts
#> 6           Pants      0153-0157-0159-       Fashion/Mens Clothing/Pants
#> 7     More Shirts More 0153-0157-0158- More Fashion/Mens Clothing/Shirts
#> 8      More Pants More 0153-0157-0159-  More Fashion/Mens Clothing/Pants
```

The second `rrapply()` could also be replaced by e.g. `dplyr::bind_rows()`, `do.call(rbind, ...)` or `data.table::rbindlist()`.

Answer (score 0):

`json_string` being your JSON text:

```
library(jsonlite)
fromJSON(json_string, simplifyDataFrame = TRUE)$Category$Subcategories[, -4]
```

output:

```
             Name     Number                    Path
1 Womens Clothing 0153-0154- Fashion/Womens Clothing
2   Mens Clothing 0153-0157-   Fashion/Mens Clothing
```